# How to get updated stats for a truncated table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I want to check if tables are empty (after a truncate + reload) in a schema and I tried the following:

```
CREATE TABLE public.whatever (
    id,
    val
) AS VALUES
  (1, 2),
  (1, 2),
  (1, 2),
  (1, 2),
  (1, 2),
  (1, 2),
  (1, 2);

TRUNCATE public.whatever;
ANALYSE public.whatever;
VACUUM public.whatever;
-- stats table seems to be static in the current transaction
-- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/monitoring-stats.html
COMMIT;
-- no result, so it's empty
SELECT *
FROM public.whatever;

-- but this still shows some data in the table:
SELECT
  schemaname,
  relname,
  n_tup_ins
FROM
  pg_stat_all_tables
WHERE
  schemaname = 'public' AND relname = 'whatever'
```

When I drop and recreate the table (without values), the above shows `0` as n_tup_ins, so at least that workaround works.

```
DROP TABLE public.whatever;
CREATE TABLE public.whatever (
  id integer,
  val integer
);
```

Do I have a wrong understanding of the stats table or is this a bug?

Comment: The information in `pg_stat_all_tables` is only updated when the tables are analyzed, e.g. because of a manual `analyze`, `vacuum analyze` or through the autovacuum daemon. Information in those tables are always just **estimates**. They are usually never 100% accurate. But why check if the table is empty if you just ran a `truncate`? If the truncate succeeds without error you can be _sure_ that the table is empty.

Comment: The actual check should ensure that the table is filled. The truncate and the filling of the table happens in two different processes (csv loading). I was surprised that after a truncate, the table was not shown empty which would hide an loading error. :-(

Comment: Again: the only **reliable** way to check if the table is (non) empty is to run `select count(*) from ..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We now used the following solution to ensure that all our raw data tables were filled:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION util.assert_table_not_empty(schema_tablename TEXT)
  RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
DECLARE
  result TEXT;
BEGIN
  -- * doesn't work if the first cell would be NULL
  EXECUTE 'SELECT 1 FROM ' || schema_tablename || ' LIMIT 1'
  INTO result;

  IF result is NULL
  THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'assertion table not empty, failed for:
%', schema_tablename;
  END IF;
  RETURN result IS NULL;
END
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION raw_data.ensure_data()
  RETURNS VOID AS
$$
DECLARE
  tablename TEXT;
BEGIN


  FOR tablename IN SELECT table_schema || '.' || table_name
                   FROM information_schema.tables
                   WHERE table_schema IN ('raw_data')

  LOOP
    PERFORM util.assert_table_not_empty(tablename);
  END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

-- in the ETL parts:
SELECT raw_data.ensure_data();
```